# Resque Job and rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, resque, resque-status

I have a Resque job that I am trying to test using rspec. The job looks something like:

```
class ImporterJob

def perform
 job_key = options['test_key']
 user = options['user']
end
```

I am using Resque status so I am using the create method to create the job like so:

```
ImporterJob.create({key:'test_key',user: 2})
```

If I try to create a job the same way in an rspec test, the options appear to not be making it to the job. As in, when I insert a binding.pry after `user = options['user']`, the options hash is empty.

My rspec test looks like this:

```
describe ImporterJob do
  context 'create' do

    let(:import_options) {
      {
        'import_key' => 'test_key',
        'user' => 1,
        'model' => 'Test',
        'another_flag' => nil
      }
    }

    before(:all) do
      Resque.redis.set('test_key',csv_file_location('data.csv'))
    end

    it 'validates and imports csv data' do
      ImporterJob.create(import_options)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What happens if you pass a `Hash` with `symbols` instead of strings? `:import_key => 'test_key'`

Comment: It appears the same issue if I pass a hash.

Comment: Yep, I meant symbols. Sorry about that. I actually realized the issue but not sure how to fix it still. The jobs are being queued up but there are no workers to run them. Is there a way in tests to start a worker to run a job?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For unit-testing it is not advisable to run the code you are testing on a different thread/process (which is what Requeue is doing). Instead you should *simulate* the situation by running it directly. Fortunately, `Resque` has a feature called [`inline`](https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/50e6f3e2649c85b447cb152ab42659ad5dcbe7ff/lib/resque.rb):

```
  # If 'inline' is true Resque will call #perform method inline
  # without queuing it into Redis and without any Resque callbacks.
  # If 'inline' is false Resque jobs will be put in queue regularly.
  # @return [Boolean]
  attr_writer :inline

  # If block is supplied, this is an alias for #inline_block
  # Otherwise it's an alias for #inline?
  def inline(&block)
    block ? inline_block(&block) : inline?
  end
```

So, your test should look like this:

```
it 'validates and imports csv data' do
  Resque.inline do
    ImporterJob.create(import_options)
  end
end
```

Comment: I tried using Resque.inline, and now the job isn't even being queued up. Not sure if I am missing something.

Comment: The job is not supposed to be queued up, it is supposed to run, well... inline. You can see the implementation here - https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/master/lib/resque/job.rb